# How do I report Magento bugs and submit bugfixes so that they are likely to be closed?

Tags: magento-1, core, bug

I found a bug in Magento 1.x and I also found a bugfix for it. Where do I report it? Where do I have a chance that a Magento core developer has a look at it? The [Magento bug tracker](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking) seems to be ignored and unmaintained (see e.g. [this issue](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=14428)).

You can actually sign the [Magento Contributor Agreement](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/be-part-of-the-solution-become-a-magento-contributor/) in order to submit patches, but I heard that even these patches are often refused. So is there any other way to get a patch into the Magento core?

With [Magento 2 on GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2), everything seems to become better. But I think there should also be a place for Magento 1 bugfixes...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just spoke to Magento community manager today and besides other things I raised this question. He agreed that this is an issue and assured that they are working on it and will make a community contribution clockwork run again soon.

How soon? Who knows. Until then there's unfortunately no alternative.

Comment: This has been the message for years. Magento 2 has github + pull requests.

Comment: I never understood why Mage 1 is not on GitHub too. I have asked and received some vague reasons ....  (eg working on even better system. Poke us on Twitter and it'll get fixed). The minute they put it up I think many improvements and bug fixes come flying in.

Comment: Don't hold your breath, I submitted a critical vulnerability over 6 months ago and they are still "working on it".  Popping a 0-day would get them moving, but fortunately ethics won't allow that.

Comment: @marius, Please read comments and reply