# How to contribute patches to Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1

What are the requirements for a patch to get accepted and included into magento 1 and what is the best way to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking) is the correct url. But there is also [How do I report Magento bugs and submit bugfixes so that they are likely to be closed?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128/how-do-i-report-magento-bugs-and-submit-bugfixes-so-that-they-are-likely-to-be-c) here in Magento Stack Exchange. I think the question is old and the URL i added here is the way to report issues.

Answer (score 1):

This quesetion is somewhat old and may be outdated :)

In my opinion it's a waste of time to post issues to Magentos (M1) issue tracker. Either it's posted and nothing happens, or they tell *"it should be solves in version x.y.z"*, or they refer to there internal JIRA issue tracker.

So my recommendation to **you** *(:P)* is using a well maintained fork that accepts approved bugfixes and improvements - like [Magento-LTS](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts) does. If you find an issue, just open a ticket there and you can bet it will be included in time.

*Even if it didn't answer your question, I hope you could smile a bit about it :)*